# how to add #{authenticityToken /} to all playframework forms

Tags: scala, playframework, csrf, playframework-1.x, csrf-token

I am using playframework 1.7 and i want to inject `#{authenticityToken /}`  to each and every form as mentioned in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/security under the `Cross-Site Request Forgery` section.

I have hundreds of form in my project, is there a way to inject this in all the forms instead of manually going to each of the forms and adding `#{authenticityToken /}` manually?

Comment: Does a play 1.7 exist? from the docs I can only see that from 1.5 it goes to 2.0. How to add tag to all your forms depends how you build your app? are you using a template framework? do you have like some kind of generic as a base template and then you add some things? please add more details about how you design you app

Comment: ```play --version


~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.7.x-proj-1.7.1.1, https://www.playframework.com
~ framework ID is local```

Comment: @GastónSchabas yes i am using the play template, no i do not have a base template.

Comment: Not having a base template means that you have to manually write each page. Sounds like you are not taking advantage of compose components to build the page. Not sure how hard is to do that now, but that would help you to evolve any app. Based on what you said, there is no other way than manually add that tag to each form. If you have the chance, consider to create a base template. It will save you time in the future. Also I strongly suggest to consider upgrade play and scala. Those versions are really old and they could have security issues